# Предложение скрывать неинтересные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

Как можно увидеть на снимке, тут лишь один вопрос на весь экран, который мне интересен. Оставлять остальные затенённые игнорируемые вопросы это ведь не рационально. Ведь их можно вовсе убрать, тем самым увеличив вероятность того, что пользователю попадётся вопрос, на который он смог бы ответить, так как на экране будет, скажем, 10 вопросов вместо одного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Чтобы убрать вопросы с игнорируемыми метками, нужно зайти в Профиль > Править > Параметры:

> [image: screenshot]

Для более эффективной фильтрации вопросов я рекомендую поменять закладку для сайта, и заходить по следующему адресу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting

Этот вариант основной страницы сайта показывает больше вопросов, и притом учитывает предпочтения участника по меткам. На английской версии он уже давно [используется по умолчанию](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) (хотя теперь его планируют заменить, но проект новой навигации застрял на бета-версии).

Comment: Куда должно вести http://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting ? Все вкладки на странице неактивны.

Comment: На основную страницу сайта, но с надписью "Лучшие вопросы" в левом верхнем углу.

Comment: О, а есть запрос на избранное? Всмысле, только вопросы по избранным тэгам? Или как такое оформить, чтобы мне интересные вопросы видеть?

Comment: @Monk Да, такое тоже есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20intags%3amine